# this simple capitaliser only works on words not sentences

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want it to capitalize every other leter:`JuSt LiKe tHiS`,but not working on a long sentence

```
def capitalise():
   
    x=input("enter the word= ")
    
    a=0
    
    while a < len(x): 
        if x[a].islower():
            x = x[:a] + x[a].upper() + x[a+1:]
            a = a + 2
    print (x)
```

Comment: Why is not working?

Comment: needs more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the increment out of the `if` clause, otherwise it will remain inside the `while` loop:

```
def capitalise():
    x = input("enter the word= ")

    a = 0

    while a < len(x):
        if x[a].islower():
            x = x[:a] + x[a].upper() + x[a + 1:]
        a = a + 2 # this line changed
    print(x)
```

A more efficient way (and a bit more *pythonic*) is to use iterate over the characters using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) as follows:

```
def capitalise():
    x = input("enter the word= ")
    characters = list(x)
    result = "".join([c.upper() if i % 2 == 0 else c for i, c in enumerate(characters)])
    print(result)
```